# Finding an MLE fit when a model predicts two kinds of data, each with a different distribution / data model

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, continuous-data, discrete-data

My problem is as follows:

I am fitting some multi-parameter models which predict two different kinds of data.

I can find a best (MLE) fit to the first kind of data. I'm currently expressing both the model predictions and the data as a multinomial distribution. In this case I get an exact probability that a particular model/parameter combination generates the data.

I can also find a best (MLE) fit to the second kind of data. This is a bit more ropey, as the errors are correlated (it's a time series), but I think I have a reasonable approximation using a multivariate normal distribution and taking an educated guess at an appropriate covariance matrix. Here, the likelihood that a particular model/parameter combination generates the data is taken from the multivariate normal distribution, so this is not an exact probability.

My problem is how to find a combined best fit to both kinds of data at once. Can I just combine the (log) likelihoods to effectively scalarize what seems like a multi-objective optimization problem? This feels slightly dodgy, given the exact vs. arbitrarily scaled nature of the two objective functions, but it also feels like that scaling should just fall out as a constant when I take logs, leaving all data weighted appropriately. However, my maths is too awful to be trusted. Apologies if this is an unusually dumb question, but can anyone advise?

Comment: The question is not dumb. The data type you are working on is called mixed data. I worked on what seems to be a very similar problem during my thesis. And in the end I had to find a hand-made combination of MLE and it prove to work well. It was in the scope of HMMs but based on MLE. Here is the reference, if you think it may help and have no access to it, I will write a full answer tomorrow: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7340853/
In this case however, I assumed that the correlation in the time series was represented by the HMM parameters, and not directly through a covariance matrix...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It looks like I have access, so I'll take a look and see if I can apply your work to my problem.

Comment: Look at the references in the related work, it will give you several other options too. Somehow, the simplest way of combining the likelihoods worked in my case, but more sophisticated combinations may work better.